# Random packet loss with bonded interfaces?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, network-interface, bonding, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to setup a LACP bond using systemd-networkd on an arch server.

When I try to ping the gateway I seem to be getting intermittent package loss which lead me to believe the LACP isn't setup correctly.

The server only seems to be using eth0 and not eth1. The switch shows that the port is active that eth0 is connected too while the port eth1 is connected too is a non-candidate for the LACP connection.

The bonded interface receives the dhcp settings just fine.

What is wrong with the following configuration for a LACP connection using linux bonding and networkd?

```
#/etc/systemd/network/bond0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond
[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
LACPTransmitRate=fast
MIIMonitorSec=1s

#/etc/systemd/network/bond0.network
[Match]
Name=bond0
[Network]
BindCarrier=enp4s0f[01]
DHCP=ipv4

#/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0fX.network
[Match]
Name=enp4s0f[01]
[Network]
Bond=bond0
```